# ReportViewer não carrega no Internet Explorer 11

Tags: c#, mvc, reportviewer

Estou tentando abrir um relatório com o `ReportViewer` no `Internet Explorer 11` e o mesmo não abre por completo. Isso ocorre com a aplicação publicada em um servidor de aplicação, mas quando executo o relatório local na minha maquina de desenvolvimento com o `visual studio 2015` instalado, o relatório abre perfeitamente.
A imagem abaixo exibe o como parte do relatório está sendo exibido no servidor de aplicação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo está a imagem do relatório sendo carregado em modo debug:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O relatório também abre perfeitamente em versões anteriores do `IE`, no `Chrome` e outros browsers. Mas preciso que o mesmo funcione no `IE11`.
Acredito que esteja faltando instalar algo no servidor, pois o mesmo está funcionando em modo debug, em minha máquina com o `VS2015` instalado.

O código no `Web.Config` que faz referência ao `ReportViewer` está abaixo:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
  </assemblies>        
  <buildProviders>
    <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
  </buildProviders>
</compilation>
```

Answer (score 1):

Já tive esse problema. Consegui resolvê-lo através do acréscimo da tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">
```

Dentro da `<head>` da página. 
Encontrei isso nos foruns da MSDN.

Comment: Minha página está dentro de uma masterPage, tentei incluir este meta e não deu certo.